# Im working on a makefile which should build a library and then also include that library when building the entire program

Tags: c++, makefile

```
INC_DIR = ./include
SRC_DIR = ./src
OBJ_DIR = ./obj
SRC_FILES = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp))
H_FILES = $(wildcard $(INC_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJ_FILES=$(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cc,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(SRC_FILES)
TARGET = PT3
CC = g++
CFLAGS = - fPIC -c -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=c++11 -Wno-c++11-extensions
CPPFLAGS = $(addprefix -I, $(INC_DIR))


clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

g++ -shared -fPIC -o libtest.so $(OBJECTS)

main.o: main.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -L/pt3/lib -o maintest main.cc -libtest
```

this is currently what I have and i know its not syntactically right or remotely working but Im getting stuck on creating the shared library so I dont even know what else wouldnt compile.**

```
INC_DIR = ./include
SRC_DIR = ./src
SRC_FILES = $(sort $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -name '*.cc'))
OBJ_FILES = $(SRC_FILES:.cc=.o)
TARGET = PT3
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -fPIC -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=c++11 -Wno-c++11-extensions
CPPFLAGS = $(addprefix -I, $(INC_DIR))


#clean:
#   rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

libtest.so: $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CC) -shared -fPIC -o $@ $^

maintest: main.o libtest.so
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -L. -o maintest main.o -libtest
```

this is what i rewrote the code to however Im getting a no input files error, but Im not sure if thats coming from a wrong read / failure to get into the required folders, or due to possibly missing a -o or -c?

Ive worked on the code some more following the suggestions and have come to this:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS := -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=c++11 -Wno-c++11-extensions
SRC_FILES = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(SRC_FILES))
INC_DIR = include
SRC_DIR = src
OBJ_DIR = obj
TEST_DIR = tests
LIB_DIR = lib


$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -fPIC -Iinclude -o $@ -c $<


clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TEST_DIR)/main.o


$(LIB_DIR)/libtest.so: $(OBJECTS)
    @echo frank
    $(CXX) -shared -fPIC -o $@ $^

$(TEST_DIR)/main.o: $(TEST_DIR)/main.cc
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -Iinclude -o $@ -c $<

maintest: $(TEST_DIR)/main.o $(LIB_DIR)/libtest.so
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -Llib -Iinclude -o $@ $< -ltest
```

everything seems to compile fine however when running the maintest program it returns an error saying: `error while loading shared libraries: libtest.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

thanks for the suggestions so far I feel like Im on the verge of actually getting the makefile working as intended

Comment: I would put link option in `$(TARGET)`(/libtest.so) rule, instead of in `main.o` rule.

Answer (score 0):

You've already written the recipe for the library (which builds it in the working directory -- we can change that later if you want):

```
g++ -shared -fPIC -o libtest.so $(OBJECTS)
```

The next step is to put it into a rule:

```
libtest.so: $(OBJECTS)
    g++ -shared -fPIC -o libtest.so $(OBJECTS)
```

Then clean it up:

```
libtest.so: $(OBJECTS)
    g++ -shared -fPIC -o $@ $^
```

It looks as if you want the executable to be `maintest`, so let's write a rule for that:

```
maintest: main.o libtest.so
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -L. -o maintest main.o -ltest
```

Give that a try. We can make further adjustments once that much works.

**EDIT:** I see that there are a few other problems in your makefile. Your variables won't work as written. Do you name your source files "foo.cc" or "foo.cpp"?

**EDIT:** I can see that we'll have to do this in stages.

Step 1. Try this:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS := -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=c++11 -Wno-c++11-extensions

INC_DIR = include
SRC_DIR = src
OBJ_DIR = obj

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -Iinclude -o $@ -c $<
```

Try to build one or two object files with this, as in `make obj/foo.o`.

Step 2. Add a rule for `main.o`, and test it:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/main.o: main.cc
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -Iinclude -o $@ -c $<
```

Step 3. Add a "do nothing" rule for the library, and verify that it builds all of the objects:

```
SRC_FILES = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(SRC_FILES))

libtest.so: $(OBJECTS)
    @echo doing nothing
```

Step 4. Change the library rule to actually build the library:

```
libtest.so: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -shared -fPIC -o $@ $^
```

Step 5. Add a rule to build the test:

```
maintest: main.o libtest.so
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -L. -o $@ $< -ltest
```

Comment: I named them .cpp except for the main.cc which is in essense a testing program which has to refer to another program through an interface